# Check whenever object is ready for use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object in javascript:

```
var Car = {
    data: {
        "wheels": 4,
        "colour": "red",
    },
    changeColour: function(colour){
        Car.coulour = colour;
    },
}
```

I need to implement this functionality:

```
var car_obj = Car || {}
car_obj.isReady = function(){
    car_obj.changeColour("blue");
};
```

`isReady` should wait till object is ready for use and make some operations on object then. How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: It's something like "observable" design pattern. You should look to KnockoutJS => http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I need to use jQuery or pure javascript only.

Comment: So write javascript code for "observable" pattern... and your result will be the same as Knockout...

Comment: What makes this object ready for use? Not enough information given

Comment: what is the meaning of `object is ready for use`? is there an event?

Comment: It should works in this way: Everything that is in `isReady` function should be called when instance of `Car` object is created and ready for use to prevent errors of type: call of undefined.

Comment: `Car` is an object, you can't create instances of objects. You can derive new objects from objects using `Object.create` though. That said, the "functionality description" creates a copy of the reference to `Car`, or if it doesn't exist, a new empty object. In the latter case `car_obj.isReady()` will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

```
var Car = {
    data: {
        "wheels": 4,
        "colour": "red"
    },
    changeColour: function(colour){
        Car.data.colour = colour; // <----should be changed to Car.data.colour
    } // <---- , not required.
}
```

Now you can use `hasOwnProperty()` method:

```
var car_obj = Car || {}
car_obj.isReady = function(){
    for(var key in car_obj){
      if(car_obj.hasOwnProperty(car_obj[key])){ // <---this lets you check if car_obj 
          car_obj.changeColour("blue");           // has changeColour property.
      }
    }
};

car_obj.isReady(); // <----run it to see.
```

---

Using `Object.observe()` can be done like:

```
Object.observe(Car, function(changes){

    // This asynchronous callback runs
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
        console.log(change); // log the changes.
    });

});
```

Comment: It works but is there any way to call this function automatically without `car_obj.isReady()'? What if my instance of `Car` object will be not created error will occur? Function should wait until object is created.

Comment: _Car object will be not created error will occur?_ sure but if you want to access it's properties you have to create an object that's why you have this `var car_obj = Car || {}`, now about automatically that you can make use of Observers then.

Comment: I can see, so there is no way to use it like I wanted: `car_obj.isReady=...` without `observe` etc?

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do about it but `observers` made a great impact, most of the front-end mv* frameworks uses this for two-way data bindings which looks for changes and updates.

Comment: Sad but, I will say something more maybe it will help you to understand me what I wanted to achive. So I have methods in this `Car` object that load data from `localStorage` for example it loads `colour, wheels, etc.` and I want to make some operations on this object data ie. get car model. When I use `nanobuy.getModel();` it returns null because it object didn't load data yet but when I use it in `$(document).ready(function(){});` it will show data. That's what I want to wait till object load all data then make some operations on it. Can I achive it?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `CAR` a constructor wrapper:

```
function Car(data) {
    //Build base
    var Car = {
        data : {
            "wheels" : 4,
            "colour" : "red",
        },
        changeColour : function (colour) {
            Car.data.colour = colour;
        }
    }
    //Parse inputs
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
        if (typeof data['colour'] !== 'undefined') {
            Car.changeColour(data['colour']);
        }
    }
    //Return object
    return Car;
};

var car = new Car({
    colour : 'blue'
});
console.log(car);
```

That way you are sure the object has finished "building" before you try to assign anything.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of asynchronous code is done in JavaScript with two different ways:

1. callbacks
2. promises

#### Callbacks

This solution involves passing a function to the object constructor which will be called from the constructor's code when the object is ready:

```
var Car = function(ready) {
   var self = this;
   self.data = { /* ... */ };
   self.changeColour = { /* ... */ };
   // invoke ready, when the object is read:
      ready();
   return self;
}

var runWhenCarReady = function() { /* */ }
var car = new Car(runWhenReady);
```

#### Promises

Your constructor should return a promise, which will be resolved when the constructor has finished its work.

```
var Car = function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); // jQuery promises implementation
    // ...
    // when ready run this code to return the value wrapped in the promise:
         deferred.resolve(self.this);
    // ...
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The code that uses the constructor should do this:

```
var promise = Car().then(function(car) {
    // car is available here
}
```

Solutions that involve object polling are not a good idea because they will block the web page.

You can read about promises in `jQuery.Deferred` or [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), or search the web for "JavaScript promises".

#### Final note

This is only necessary when there is involved asynchronous code. If not, JavaScript "runs in order" so you have the warranty that what you create in a line of code is available in the next one. I suppose you're over-simplifying your sample.

The most common case of JavaScript asynchronicity are the AJAX invocations. And, in the case of jQuery they use the promise pattern.